# Overriding default MVC 4 validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to change the behavior of the default validation in a MVC 4 application. Specifically I want to change the model properties that have already been marked with '`DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)`'.

I want to force all model properties marked with '`phonenumber`' application wide to only recognize the format '`(nnn) nnn-nnnn`' as valid. Also if possible, reformat to the valid format if 10 digits are present. I could create the needed code if I can find what classes that need to be overridden or added.

So far I have only seen ways to create custom validation attributes, not override the existing validators.

Comment: Use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute.

Comment: That will not enforce the validation on all phone number fields nor does it all me to strongly type the property in the metadata. I would need to update every model. Best practice would be to override the existing behavior so that the model that are annotated with the correct datatype to trigger the expected behavior, current as well as future.